# Can't add another event notification to an S3 that already had one

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an S3 bucket that already has an existing event notification to **SQS**,it looks like below:

| Name | Event type | Filters | Destination type | Destination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s3_put_sqs | All object create events | rawlog/ | SQS queue | ilpslog_processor_queue |

I tried to **manually** add another event notification in the AWS console which the destination is a **Lambda function**, so that the event notification will look like this :

| Name | Event type | Filters | Destination type | Destination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s3_put_sqs | All object create events | rawlog/ | SQS queue | ilpslog_processor_queue |
| s3_put_lambda | All object create events | output/ | Lambda function | testLambda |

But I kept receiving the error message: "*Unable to validate the following destination configurations*"

I have tried the following already:

- Gave temporary **full permission** to the lambda execution role
- Modified the lambda function's resource-based policy to give S3 the permissions:

  - *lambda:InvokeFunction*
  - *lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration*
  - *lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration*
  - *lambda:GetFunction*
- Tried to use **PUT** event type on the *s3_put_lambda*

I have also tried to do this on a different S3 bucket that had **no existing event notification** - and it worked without adjusting anything which led me to believe that the problem is in the S3 bucket.

The S3 bucket and Lambda function are in the same region.

Any insights will help. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you have tried everything possible to diagnose this situation. Have you tried adding the Trigger from within the Lambda management console, rather than the S3 management console? Would you be willing to temporarily remove the SQS target and see whether you can add the Lambda target? (The messages would just sit in the queue.)

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the reply. Yes and it shows the same error message, and yes I think I can temporarily remove the SQS target to test. Will update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Target queue of existing event notif has invalid access policy**

The destination of the existing event notif is a queue, and the queue uses an **invalid** policy. This might have caused an issue on the validation on AWS side which was triggered when I tried adding a new event notif.

Sharing here the steps that I did to discover and then resolve the issue:

1. Temporarily event notif (existing) to SQS (thanks to [John Rotenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein) for the tip)
2. Added the event notif (new) to Lambda and **succeed**
3. Re-added the event notif to SQS but **failed** and got the *Unable to validate the following destination configurations* error prompt
4. Checked policy of the target queue, discovered it was **invalid**
5. Corrected the policy of target queue
6. Re-added the event notif to SQS and succeded